# how can i fix that error about android webdriver in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, android-webview

i know this problem is very easy for you, but at me is very difficult

i want make autotesting my web by android driver

and i found this
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android

so I installed for starting android test

selenium server - https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

java - https://www.java.com/ko/download/windows-64bit.jsp

facebook/php-webdriver - https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver

laravel - in console

android studio -https://developer.android.com/studio/install?hl=ko

and i did setup Environment in my computer, like below this

[image]
[image]
finally i start selenium server in my console like below

```
' $ java -jar selenium ~~~~~~ '
```

and testing is success by desktop chrome driver.

but it is failed for android driver

my code about selenium is

```
/ start Chrome with 5 second timeout
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::android();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
$driver->get('https://www.seleniumhq.org/');
```

it is fail and error code is

```
Unable to create session from { "desiredCapabilities": { "browserName": 
"android", "platform": "ANDROID" }, "capabilities": { "firstMatch": [ { 
"browserName": "android", "platformName": "android" } ] } } Build info: 
version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' 
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-N27RM9V', ip: '192.168.0.4', os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211' Driver 
info: driver.version: unknown
```

how can i  solve here situation
help me,,,,,, please tell me how can solve this,,,,,

I hope you understand if I make a mistake because my english level is very low and thanks you for reading